# Problems with running Android Activity unit-testing from Eclipse

Tags: android, unit-testing

Im having a problem starting or running any activity unit tests from within eclipse.

Even i start a clean project and make a simple test class it always prints to the console:

```
[2010-10-05 13:10:24 - testAndroid] Collecting test information
[2010-10-05 13:10:25 - testAndroid] Test run failed: Test run incomplete. Expected 2 tests, received 0
```

Any ideas ?

Just for testing, I have created a fresh Android project called Demo with a test project called DemoTest

The main activity to test is called Main and I have created a simple testclass MainTest that looks like this:

```
package net.demo.test;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import net.demo.Main;

    public class MainTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Main>
    {

        public MainTest()
        {
            super("net.demo", Main.class);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
    }
```

My tests used to run fine before, but suddenly I cant run any of them, they all fail with the same error, even I create new a project. It seems like it something to do with Eclipse or and not with the Code.

**Update:**
Seems like extending `SingleLaunchActivityTestCase<Main>` is working, but still got no clue about how to make `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Main>` working.

Comment: If it worked before, maybe send us a diff showing changes from a working version?  (You did commit the working version to source control before making changes, right?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had no regression problems. I just couldn't get the example to work. I finally fixed it by defining *two* constructors:

```
public MainActivityTest(String pkg, Class<MainActivity> activityClass) {
    super("com.myapp", MainActivity.class);
}

public MainActivityTest() {
    super("com.myapp", MainActivity.class);
}
```

It turned out that most emulators before 2.3.3 were silently swallowing the error generated when construction went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You must put at least 2 methods (i.e 2 test cases) into the Test class. even methods without definition inside can do the trick